# function.prototype.method

Tags: javascript

I would like to ask about the code below

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
   this.prototype[name] = func;
   return this;
};
```

Does that mean that "Function" and any new function will inherit functions created by method?

To make it more clear

```
Function.method('test', function () {return 1;});
```

is test now available to be called as a method on Function or any other function or not?

Answer (score 2):

No, `this` inside a function refers to the object on which it was called. In this case, that should be a function, and more specifically, a constructor function. It should be used like:

```
function SomeObject() {}

SomeObject.method('doSomething', function() {
    alert('Something!');
});

new SomeObject().doSomething(); // Something!
```

Comment: Try to define the function using the code I have attached above. After defining a function this way, I haven't been able to find it on Function's prototype or any other function. It was only available in objects created by the function and I don't know why ?!

Comment: @MostafaMahmoud: Ah, sorry, I misread `this` as `Function`. It’s supposed to be used on constructors. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a protypical language. When a function is called on an object and not found a search begins up the prototype chain. It will search all objects in the prototype chain until the prototype chain ends at `Object`, the parent of all objects.

All functions inherit from `Function` either directly or indirectly, meaning all functions will have your specified "method", even functions that have already been created.

---

```
Function.prototype.printSup = function () { console.log('sup'); }
Math.max.printSup();
String.pringSup();
'asdf'.substr.printSup()
```

Comment: The parent of all objects! Except for DOM nodes in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier, you know, *because*.

Comment: Try to define the function using the code I have attached above. After defining a function this way, I haven't been able to find it on Function's prototype or any other function. It was only available in objects created by the function and I don't know why ?!

Comment: @MostafaMahmoud I dont understand, I updated my answer to include examples.